# setter not setting session variable in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a controller that counts the number of times the user has been to a page.  I'm trying to extract that count to a getter and setter which set a session variable.  Getting works, but setting doesn't.  This is the controller:

```
class StoreController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @products = Product.order(:title)

        v = store_visits + 1
        store_visits = v  # tests fail if I do it like this

        # store_visits += 1  # Undefined method '+' for NilClass if i do it like this

        @visits = store_visits
    end

    def store_visits
        if session[:store_counter].nil?
            session[:store_counter] = 0
        end
        session[:store_counter]
    end 

    def store_visits=(value)
        session[:store_counter] = value
    end
end
```

And here's a failing test:

```
require 'test_helper'

class StoreControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
    test "should count store visits" do
        get :index
        assert session[:store_counter] == 1
        get :index
        assert session[:store_counter] == 2
    end
end
```

Why isn't it setting, and why is store_visits returning nil if I use `+=` ?  Any help is appreciated.

Note: Originally I extracted the methods to a concern, but I've edited this to remove the concern, because the problem isn't with the concern, it's with the setter and/or getter.

**Update:** After adding logging statments, it's obvious that the inside of the store_visits=() method is never reached (but somehow an error is not thrown).  However, if I rename it to assign_store_visits(), it does get called, and does update the session variable.  So I'm guessing this is either a bug where setter methods don't work in controllers (this is Rails 4.0.0) or they're intentionally blocked (in which case, an exception would be nice).

Comment: how looks you `config/initializer/session_store.rb`

Comment: It has one (non-comment) line:
`Depot::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_depot_session'`

Answer (score 0):

try switch to `include ActiveSupport::Concern`

this will provide instance methods instead class methods

Comment: Didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the methods inside of your concern inside of an included block like:

```
module Visits
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
    #private

        def store_visits
            if session[:store_counter].nil?
                session[:store_counter] = 0
            end
            session[:store_counter]
        end 

        def store_visits=(value)
            session[:store_counter] = value
        end

    # private
    end
  end
end
```

Doing that will make those methods available as instance methods inside of your controller.

Comment: It still behaves the same.  The problem doesn't seem to be that they're not available but that store_visits=() doesn't seem to be doing the right thing.  store_visits() returns what's in the session variable when called from the controller, but if I do store_visits +=, I'm guessing it would implicitly call store_visits() first, and that behaves as if it's returning nil.  But when I just do it as a set, ( store_visits = v ), it doesn't set, because store_visits() still returns 0.  I'm wondering if it's somehow looking at a different "session".

Comment: What's really weird is that it still fails when I move the methods to the StoreController itself.